# How to resolve the requested resource is not available error in spring boot which runs on tomcat server?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8, centos-web-panel

I had successfully run my spring boot application in localhost.

[image]

But when I had run it from the CWP panel tomcat server, I am getting the error given below. How to resolve this error? Do I need anything else to run on a CWP panel tomcat server?

[image]

Steps which I had followed

1. Extends the SpringBootServletInitializer class in the main class.

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class GDriveAppJavaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
     @Override
     protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure( SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(GDriveAppJavaApplication.class);
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(GDriveAppJavaApplication.class, args);
     }

   }
   ```
2. Update packaging JAR to WAR
3. Added Tomcat starter dependency with scope as provided

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
   ```
4. Application properties

   ```
    server.servlet.context-path=/GDriveAppJava
   ```
5. Generated war file(GDriveAppJava) and copied to webapps folder in the tomcat as shown below.

[image]

6. Controller file

   ```
   @RestController
   @AllArgsConstructor
   public class FileController {

      @Autowired
      private FileManager fileManager;

      @Autowired
      private FileRepository fileRepository;

      @PostMapping(value = "/upload/{user_id}")
      public ResponseEntity<FileEntity> uploadFIle(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,@PathVariable String user_id){
          FileEntity updated = fileManager.uploadFile(file, user_id);
          return new ResponseEntity<FileEntity>(updated, HttpStatus.OK);
      }

      @GetMapping(path="/viewByUserId/{user_id}")
      public List<FileEntity> viewByUserid(@PathVariable String user_id) 
      {
           return fileRepository.findByUserId(user_id);
      }

      @GetMapping("/downloadFile/{file_id}")
      public void download(@PathVariable String file_id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
         fileManager.downloadFile(file_id, response.getOutputStream());
      }

      @GetMapping(path="/viewByFileId/{file_id}")
      public List<FileEntity> viewByFileId(@PathVariable String file_id) 
      {
         return fileRepository.findByFileId(file_id);
      }
   ```

   }

**Application properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/user123_gdriveapp
spring.datasource.username=user123//my server username
spring.datasource.password=password123//my server password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql: true


spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=100MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=100MB

server.servlet.context-path=/GDriveAppJava
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1:** You need to generate a war file and deploy it to the tomcat server. Referring to https://codezup.com/deploy-spring-boot-war-to-external-tomcat/ for generating war file.

**Step 2:** Search the war file to target folder. Then rename the war file. for example: gdapp.war. Then depoloy the .war file to the tomcat server.

**Step 3:** Access the application using the file name in the URL. example: gdapp/GDriveAppJava/...

**Note: Make sure you have configured your database properly.**

Comment: What is GDriveAppJava in this?

Comment: See the uri. You named your project folder GDriveAppJava

Comment: Md. Sakhawath Hossain   But you have mentioned both gdapp also right and URL should like projectFolderName/getMethodname right?

Comment: When you upload the .war file in the webapp make sure you rename the the file. Then add the file name at the start of the URI. My project worked in this way in external tomcat server.